# Height constraint prevents resizing of NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, interface-builder, nswindow

I'm trying to get the hang of NSViewConstraints. I like them a lot; they make a lot more sense to me than the previous system.

I have a window, a 22 pixel-tall subview spanning the top of it, and a tabless, borderless NSTabView beneath it. The goal is to have the top subview never resize its height.

Without any constraints, auto formatting takes care of most of the work. The only trouble is resizing the window causes the upper subview to change its height. My seemingly logical response was to pin the height at 22. I left margin constraints alone, since the NSTabView was already handling resizing well.

By pinning the height of the upper subview, the window now refuses to resize vertically! I don't see any documentation anywhere saying this is expected or the logic behind it. I've messed with various constraint configurations to overcome it but nothing works.

Two questions:

1. Why is pinning the height of one subview freezing window height resizing? What is Xcode's logic?
2. What constraint setup will achieve the desired positioning?

Comment: Are you sure that's the only constraint you have?

Comment: The only user-defined one, yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested creating a window as you describe, and pinning the height of the 22px view. This created one user constraint on the view for it's height.

However, it also created 2 constraints on the parent view (the window's content view), one for the Top Space to the 22px view, and a second for the Bottom Space to the 22px view. These constraints are what's preventing you from resizing your window. You should select the second constraint and delete it (but leave the first one in place as it's fine).

Comment: Amazing! I thought I had tried every combo out there. Didn't even notice those were being tossed in automatically. Thanks!